# Php artisan displaying strange characters on windows command prompt

Tags: laravel

Please can anyone help me with this error I'm getting on command prompt for windows 10. Whenever I try to utilize the php artisan feature in Laravel 5.2 I get this error.
I've tried running "system file checker command: sfc /scannow"  but the error still persists.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are [color codes](http://pueblo.sourceforge.net/doc/manual/ansi_color_codes.html). Use another terminal app if it annoys you. I'd recommend to install Git for Windows which will install pretty cool [mintty](https://mintty.github.io) terminal app.

Comment: Thanks friend, i'm now using "power shell" n its working well

Answer (score 4):

That's not an error. Those are [color codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), which the Windows terminal apparently doesn't support.

<sup>There's an uncited note on the Wikipedia article that Windows 10 TH2 patch version does. YMMV.</sup>

Here's what they look like in a terminal that supports them:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Windows PowerShell works perfectly with color codes and other ANSI codes. Even if I find it somehow less "responsive" than the old command prompt.

Comment: yeah i have noticed that it's less responsive too